# Changing image dimensions & keeping it responsive

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know, is it possible to change `img` dimensions while preserving its responsiveness on browser resize? Applying `height` and `width` doesn't work.

```css
.wrap1 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img1 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="wrap1">
      <img class="img1" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When resizing this jsfiddle, it is responsive. https://jsfiddle.net/oudzd14e/  Can you help clarify what you expect to happen?

Comment: I know it works, but how can you adjust the size of the image suppose you want it smaller? @JoshAdams

Comment: Do you want the image to be responsive, but you want to be able to specify a dimension also, right?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, but to hazard a guess, have you considered an element with a background image set to `background-size: cover;`?

Comment: vertical & horizontal responsiveness or just horizontal?